# How to remove yahoo redirect from google?

Tags: mac, browser, malware, google-search

Although Chrome works fine, in safari, whenever I make a Google search, the results are returned in yahoo search, which suggests a malware in my Mac. How can I detect and remove this malware?

Comment: Could you list your installed browser extensions, if any?

Comment: ad block is the only one

Comment: okay there's this extension OptimalPromo that gets re-installed automatically even when I delete it.